# Как получить sizeof данных по указателю, не используя ссылку?

Tags: c++

Как получить sizeof данных по указателю, не используя ссылку?

Answer (score 5):

> Если написать типа : `int* ptr_int = ... int& link = *ptr_int; sizeof (link);` то выдаст размер данных, а как сделать тоже самое, но не прибегая к ссылке?

У тебя в вопросе, похоже, парсер съел звёздочки. Если я их правильно поставил, то ответ на вопрос такой: `sizeof(*ptr_int)`.

sizeof позволяет узнать только размер, известный во время компиляции. Если у тебя будет класс `B` наследоваться от класса `A`, и будет такой код:

```
B b;
A* ptrB=&b;
cout << sizeof(*ptrB);
```

то на экран будет выведен размер объекта класса A.

Если надо узнать размер по указателю, известный в рантайме, можно определить эти классы так:

```
class A
{
    virtual unsigned int GetMySize() {return sizeof(A);}
    int Avalue;
};

class B: public A
{
    virtual unsigned int GetMySize() {return sizeof(B);}
    double Bvalue;
};
```

Получить настоящий размер объекта можно будет так:

```
cout << ptrB->GetMySize();
```

Здесь используются виртуальные функции, которые увеличивают размер объектов, храня указатель на таблицу виртуальных функций, поэтому размеры могут отличаться.

Answer (score 1):

Если тип данных, куда указывает указатель, неизвестный, то официальными методами никак.

Comment: А если тип данных известен, но это указатель? Простое разыменование не поможет - sizeof выдаст размер указателя. Если написать типа :
int* ptr_int = ...
int& link = *ptr_int;
sizeof (link);
то выдаст размер данных, а как сделать тоже самое, но не прибегая к ссылке?

Comment: sizeof может брать размер от типа.

Comment: В этом случае sizeof выдаст размер типа, а нужно размер данных, на которые ссылается указатель.

Comment: Если написать типа : int ptr_int = ... int& link = ptr_int; sizeof (link); то выдаст размер данных
``sizeof`` всегда выдает размер типа. В данном случае ``sizeof`` выдаст размер ТД, которым является ``link``. Именно поэтому возможно такое: ``int* a = NULL; sizeof(*a)``; хотя ``a`` не указывает ни на какие данные, ``sizeof`` в compile-time смотрит каким ТД является ``*a`` и возвращает это значение.

Comment: Если в данном примере вместо int подставить какуюнить структуру, то sizeof выдаст размер данных, находящихся в структуре. Вопрос: можно ли через sizeof сделать тоже самое не используя ссылку?

Comment: Наверное самое время спросить что понимается под "размером данных"?

Answer (score 1):

Если память была выделена динамически, то можно использовать функцию [malloc_usable_size](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=malloc_usable_size&category=3&russian=1). Она может вернуть б*о*льшее значение, чем было передано *alloc при выделении, но это реальное количество памяти, которое было выделено по этому указателю. Только я плохо себе представляю, в какой ситуации может вдруг понадобиться такое... Как так получилось, что вы не знаете, сколько выделяете?)

Comment: У меня 2 программы обмениваются данными через файл, спроецированный в память. Размер данных естественно меняется, память выделяется программой и контролировать это я никак не могу, а вот для того чтобы данные спроецировать в файл необходимо знать размер этих данных. Доступ к ним я могу получить только через указатели. Вот я и пытаюсь использовать sizeof для получения размера данных. Пока получается только при использовании ссылок.

Comment: Не понятна проблема. Есть указатель, но непонятно на что? А если понятно, то почему нужен именно sizeof? А то как в win95 "Обнаружено неизвестное устройство, устанавливаю драйвер"...

Comment: а программа, которая пишет данные, знает размер данных? Если да, то никаких проблем. Можно сделать так, что бы по указателю лежали не данные, а структура известной структуры. А внутри этой структуры и размер можно положить, и указатель на данные.
Но если программы обмениваются указателями, кто мешает обменяться ещё 4 байтами размера?

Comment: Вопрос не в том как изощряться в программе, а в том можно ли при помощи sizeof по указателю на структуру или класс узнать размер данных, не прибегая к помощи ссылки?

Comment: Вам уже ответили, что sizeof тутсовершенно не при чем и никак не сможет вам помочь. Sizeof - это директива препроцессора, она раскрывается на стадии компиляции, вам же нужно что-то, работающее в run-time. Но на самом деле вам нужно, как вы говорите, немного "поизощряться в программе", потому что при нормальной архитектуре приложения таких ситуаций возникать не должно.

Comment: Кстати слово "ссылка" в C++ имеет определённый смысл. Чего Вы хотите, можете объяснить на пальцах? А то народ пытается вычислить мотивы и дать совет, как это реализовать, а Вы -- "хочу квардатный!". Ответ "нет" @KoVadim уже дал.

Comment: Хех, кстати на счет "определенного смысла ссылок в С++", был забавный случай. Когда у нас были лекции по ЯВУ, лекторша заставляла нас писать функцию перегрузки оператора [] с возвратом ссылки и условием внутри, то есть получалось что-то такое:

    int& SOMECLASS::operator[] (int i){
        if (i<n) return A[i];     
    }

Мне этот код совершенно не нравился, и меня очень волновало, что же вернет функция, если i>=n :) У кого какие предположения?) Мне было забавно узнать)

Comment: >Sizeof - это директива препроцессора

 Нет. Директивы препроцессора - это всё, что начинается со знака `#`. sizeof действует на стадии компиляции, что позволяет его использовать, например, с шаблонами.

Comment: >У кого какие предположения?) Мне было забавно узнать)

 Какое-то левое значение. Скорее всего то, что содержится в регистре `eax`, так как возвращаемые значения передаются через него.

>лекторша заставляла нас писать функцию перегрузки оператора [] с возвратом ссылки и условием внутри, то есть получалось что-то такое:

 Ты уверен, что надо было делать такое? Надо было аварийно завершать программу или кидать исключение.

 Ещё в этом коде не предусмотрено, что i может быть <0.

Comment: Хех, я уверен, что такой проверки делать не нужно вообще. Но тот придумал не я, так что и мопед не мой, как говорится :D Она вообще была довольно странным лектором...

Хотя конечно исключение можно было бы и кинуть)

Comment: Оттранслировал (думать не хотелось). Всё нормально -- ошибка сегментирования. g++

Comment: Ну если в эту ссылку еще и писать пытаться - то конечно)) Когда я смотрел асм-код, получалось, что в eax находится значение i - оно там остается после сравнения :) Но это наверняка зависит от -OX и компилятора...

Answer (score 1):

```
const char* p1="text";
int size1=sizeof(*p1); // == 1 (аналогично sizeof(char)
int size2=sizeof(p1); // == 4 (аналогично sizeof(char*)
const char p2[]="text";
int size3=sizeof(p2); // == 5
```

Сссылки, заметьте, нигде не используются.

Если массив димаческий, то sizeof от него никак не получить - sizeof вычисляет размер занимаемой области памяти при компиляции.